# Conditional Submit Form Not Posting

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I am trying to figure out a way to have a form submit to a different page.php depending on the selection made.

The code below works in redirecting, however its not posting the information over to the next page.

Form

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="javascript:redirect();">
    <select id="man" name="man">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function redirect() {
    var Value = document.getElementById("man").value;
    if(Value == 0)
    {
        location.href = "page2.php";
    }
    else
    {
        location.href = "page3.php";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant I normally use for this cases. I think it's better than redirecting via JS:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <select id="man" name="man">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

form1.onsubmit = formSubmit;

function formSubmit() {
    var manValue = document.getElementById("man").value;

    if (manValue == 0) {
        form1.action = "page2.php";
    } else {
        form1.action = "page3.php";
    }
}
```

You just modify the form's action depending on which option was selected. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I sorted this one out. Changed the code to:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return send(this);">
<select id="man" name="man">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Continue</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function send( frm ) {
    if ( frm.man.value == "0" )
        frm.action = "page2.php";
    else
        frm.action = "page3.php";
}
</script>
```